# Rasa core: Multiple utterance not working

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am using Rasa 1.10.1
I have the following in my stories.md:

> - greet
>
>   - utter_introduction
>   - utter_ask_name_confirmation

And my domain.yml file contains responses like the following:

> responses:
> utter_introduction:
>
> - text: "Hi david, my name is Sara and I am calling from ABC bank, How are you doing today?"
> - text: "Hey there! my name is Sara and I am calling from ABC bank, How are you doing today?"
>
> utter_ask_name_confirmation:
>
> - text: "I am just verifying that I am contacting the correct person."

My problem is only **utter_introduction** *works*.

The bot just *ignores* **utter_ask_name_confirmation** !

I read from some old threads that Rasa was having this bug in some previous version. But I am using 1.10.1 which I believe is a new version.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can somebody help me to solve this issue?